# Creating a scatterplot on a personalized grid with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I did a scatterplot of two versions of a cognitive score aiming to classify some patients.
I'd like to have a colored background with different colors: dark blue when the 2 scores are classifying patients in the same category, light blue when there is one class of difference between the 2 scores, light red when there is 2 classes of difference and dark red when there is more.

I did this scatterplot with the correct grid but can't color it. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpZTi.png)

I want to have something like that but with the correct levels:
`score <11= level 1`
`score<16= level 2`
`score<21= level 3`
`score>21= level 4`
Here I just did an imshow heatmap with a [[3,2,1,0],[2,1,0,1], [1,0,1,2],[0,1,2,3]] matrix.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqzZz.png)

Thank you for your help!